# Editing Wordpress post to be full width

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to figure out if this is even worth it, but I love this theme. The problem is on this [example](http://wp.contempographicdesign.com/wp_journal/?p=488). I would like to make the post full width, if I disable the widgets they just turn blank. Is there any way to tell it to fill it with blank text?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this issue easily with CSS, better would be of course that you go remove those sidebar-calls in the code.

You can use the following CSS to make your posts container full width:

```
#left-sidebar{
    display:none;
}

#right-sidebar{
    display:none;
}

#content{
    width:940px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! _Such_ an easy fix!